# Is there any API for ether sent transaction in ethereum

Tags: ethereum

I want to do a transaction (sent ether or token) by API, not from web3.js

I have tried etherscan, block cypher

This is a get balance API code like this I want send transaction code

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xC1A71f1eFC01D77aA102A9CE248c5360C347Abc8&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                // Set Here Your Requesred Headers
                'Content-Type: application/json',
            ),
        ));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to make a RPC call to a ethereum node. Basically, web3 libraries are wrappers around this.

Docs can be found here : https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction